# Result about dyadic numbers.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, number-theory

There is a result I've seen that goes like this:

Let $k,N,i,n \in \mathbb{N}\cup\{0\}$, then if $k\cdot 2^{-N}\in[i\cdot 2^{-n},(i+1)\cdot 2^{-n})$, then there exist $r \in \mathbb{N}, \{a_l\}_{l=n+1}^r$ with each $a_l$ wither $0$ or $1$ and

$$k\cdot 2^{-N}=i\cdot2^{-n}+\sum\limits_{l=n+1}^r  a_l\cdot 2^{-l}.$$

I would like to prove this result.

**Attempt:**

I have managed to do it if we assume $N=n$, and the case $N<n$ is also simple since then $k\cdot 2^{-N}=k\cdot 2^{n-N}\cdot 2^{-n}$. This means that $k\cdot2^{-N}=i\cdot 2^{-n}.$

But I am struggling with the case $N>n$. For example in this case we have $i2^{-n}=i2^{N-n}\cdot 2^{-N}$ so we get $k2^{-N}-i2^{-n}=(k-i2^{N-n})2^{-N}$ can we use that?

I was thinking about using induction, but I didn't manage to finish the result. It is a very intuitive result, but I am not able to do it rigorously. Can you please help me?

**Update:**

I've reduced the problem to proving that if $N>n$ and there is a natural number $C$ and a real number $C_2$ such that $C_2=C \cdot 2^{-N}\in [0,2^{-n})$ then $C_2$ can be written

$$\sum\limits_{l=n+1}^r a_l \cdot 2^{-l},$$

where still the $a_l$s are either zero or one and $r$ is a suitable finite natural number.

Comment: I think you mean *dyadic* numbers

Comment: @J.W.Tanner Yes, thank you.

Comment: I assume the top index on the $a_l$ terms should run from n+1 to r when you first reference them

Comment: @CiaránÓRaghaillaigh Correct, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

For $N>n$ we have, $k-2^{N-n}i\in \mathbb{N}\cup \{0\}$ and $k-2^{N-n}i<2^{N-n}$. Thus, $k-2^{N-n}i$ had a dyadic representation,
$$k-2^{N-n}i=\sum_{l=0}^{N-n-1} 2^la_l$$
So we have, $$ 2^{-N}k=2^{-n}i+\sum_{l=-N}^{-n-1} 2^la_l=2^{-n}i+\sum_{l=n+1}^{N} 2^{-l}a_l$$

Comment: Thank you, but how do you know that every natural number has a dyadic representation with $a_l$ either 0 or 1?

Comment: Subtract the largest power of 2 from your number you can while still remaining non negative. The resulting number will be less than the power of 2 you subtracted. Induct. You will eventually be left with zero. The collection of powers of 2 you subtract give the dyadic representation.

Comment: In every step of said process, you are least, half the number, so the process takes no more steps than the highest power you subtract (plus one possibly).